# Why my xml code appear in xml layout file bu not in android device?

Tags: android

I have imported some code in android studio. The XML codes appear in the XML file resource but not in android device. My Main Activity is set in default and have no error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@color/tan_background"
android:orientation="vertical" tools:context="com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android ">

<TextView android:id="@+id/numbers"
    style="@style/CategoryStyle"
    android:background="@color/category_numbers"
    android:text="@string/category_numbers"
    android:onClick="openNumbersList"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/family"
    style="@style/CategoryStyle"
    android:background="@color/category_family"
    android:text="@string/category_family" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/colors"
    style="@style/CategoryStyle"
    android:background="@color/category_colors"
    android:text="@string/category_colors" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/phrases"
    style="@style/CategoryStyle"
    android:background="@color/category_phrases"
    android:text="@string/category_phrases" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

And this is my Main Activity:

```
package com.example.android.miwok;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public void openNumbersList(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,NumbersActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Comment: What do u mean by xml code not appearing in android device???

Comment: What do you mean by "android device"? And please put the MainActivity in here too.

Comment: @KæmpeKlunker    I mean my AVD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say your MainActivity is set in DEFAULT. If that is referring to your manifest, please change it to this:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

You need a LAUNCHER activity in order for Android to know which Activity to launch when the app starts.

Answer (score 0):

Set your xml file in your Activity as shown below:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

and set the TextView text color to black

```
android:textColor="#000"
```

Comment: Well, the OP already does use that code. And I see no reason to use only black for the text color.

Comment: Remove  android:background="@color/category_colors" ... and write like this.. android:textColor="@color/category_colors" . Change like this in all three TextViews.